# error with views in laravel project with VPS

Tags: laravel

why when I install a laravel project in my VPS, all what i've got always is an index like this? Apache, MySQL, Composer and laravel are installed. 
My server is Ubuntu 16.04

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You aren't using the path to the public directory. Set your document root to the `public` directory of the Laravel installation.

Another way to fix this problem is move your whole installation to the parent directory of the one you're showing and move the contents of the `public` directory into the current one.

Answer (score -1):

I had to configure apache2!!! it was the problem.
Here is a tutorial https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-laravel-on-ubuntu-for-apache/

:)